# What is the correct way of adding `react` as a dependency in the `package.json` of a reusable components library?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, dependencies, package.json

I built a few reusable React components, and I want to know the correct way to add `react` as a dependency in my `package.json` for the purpose of publishing to the npm registry.

I am currently doing this:

I assume that my component will use the most recent version of React, and I test that it works with the said version, e.g. 0.13.3:

```json
"peerDependencies": { 
    "react": "^0.13.3"
},
```

Answer (score 107, accepted):

For reusable components:

1. Put a `react` dependency in both `peerDependencies` and `devDependencies`.
2. **Never** put a `react` dependency in `dependencies`.

---

`peerDependencies` specifies which version(s) of React your reusable component supports/requires. When using npm 2 this also adds React to the list of modules to be installed, but this is no longer the case with npm 3.

`devDependencies` ensures React will be installed when you run `npm install` while developing your component, or when running tests on Travis or similar.

Putting `react` in `dependencies` will cause multiple versions of React to be installed if somebody uses your component but has a different version of React in their own `package.json` - having multiple versions of React not only bloats the build, but also causes errors when different versions try to interact.

Comment: If you do this, how does it work to `require('react')` in your component? It might be because I'm `npm link`ing in my component right now, but webpack can't resolve my component's `require('react')`.

Comment: Looks like `npm link` and `peerDependencies` isn't smooth. Switching to `npm pack` for local testing works correctly with webpack's `require` it seems.

Comment: How about `prop-types`? I would have assumed it should also be a `peerDependency`, but I see many examples where it's a `dependency`.

Answer (score 11):

The selected answer is definitely the prescribed approach here however I've started favoring the use of inversion of control as opposed to relying on npm peer dependencies for my libraries dependencies and its served me well.

Libraries are easier if you build them functional. It seems to be easier to maintain libraries that export a single function which takes in an object with all of their heavy dependencies and export an object containing each of your libraries typical exports.

---

#### Library 'injected'

**lib/index.js**

```
export default ({ React }) => {
  const InjectedComponent = props => (
    <p style={{color: props.color}}>This component has no React npm dependencies.</p>
  )

  /** other stuff */

  return { InjectedComponent }
}
```

---

#### Consuming App

**app.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom'

/** Import the default export factory from our library */
import createInjectedComponent from 'injected'

/** Call the factory, passing its dependencies (guaranteed to match what we're bundling) and get back our component */
const { InjectedComponent } = createInjectedComponent({ React })

render(<InjectedComponent color="blue" />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

---

If your component only works with a given version of react or some other dependency, you can write some assertions around the version for the React parameter that is passed in. Overall, building libraries in this fashion should be less prone to new build issues appearing anytime version of React is published and will more importantly ensure that you are not causing your library consumers to bundle multiple versions of React and other heavy libraries. This pattern works well with `npm` link (I generally have 16+ libraries running from `npm` link simultaneous and experienced issues when I didn't use this pattern).

In your main app I would recommend always splitting out `react`, `react dom` and any react lib components you use into a vendor bundle (webpack) and mark it as external in your main bundle so that you do not unintentionally bundle two versions.

Comment: This is pretty neat. Do you have an example of a library that uses this injection approach?

Comment: @PaulRazvanBerg thank you! I haven't seen the approach used much outside of my own work, but found the pattern worked well and sidestepped npm dependency issues. The downside to the pattern is that your library may not support future versions of React and fail silently if there are major API changes. I would recommend writing code in the lib defensively with good assertions around the parts of React functionality you expect to exist. Here is an example from one of my libs: https://github.com/noderaider/react-redux-idle-monitor/blob/master/src/lib/index.js#L26

Answer (score -3):

You can have `react` in either `peerDependencies` or in `dependencies`. The difference being that with a `peerDependencies`, `react` is only installed once for the package using your package. If you put it in `dependencies`, `react` will be installed twice, one time for the package using your package, and once time for your package.

React itself seems to favor `peerDependencies` for some reason. You obviously don't want two separate versions of `react` in your Javascript bundle (which happens by default if you use `dependencies`), but that is easy to fix with `npm dedupe`.

So there's no correct way to do it, both `peerDependencies` and `dependencies` work. Using `dependencies` is more in line with the node/NPM way, but using `peerDependencies` is friendlier to users of your package that doesn't know about `npm dedupe` and why it's needed.

Comment: this is out of date with npm 3, which will only install two versions when there is a version conflict.