# npm validation for package install

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, reactjs, npm

- I have a react app, in which folder name is sports, inside the sports
  folder I have node modules, inside the node modules folder I have
  football folder and react folder.

  - If go to football folder and do **npm install** react its installing
    react, which makes my application fail, how to prevent this
    command npm install react from being successful.
  - Is it anyway we can right a script to prevent this process to happen,
    but it should work when we do npm install react in sports folder. Is
    there any already npm packages which we use it make automatically
    validated our npm commands.

Comment: Please check the answer given at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30451556/what-is-the-correct-way-of-adding-a-dependency-to-react-in-your-package-json-for

Comment: @Munhoz but how to do it in automation