# Why does react/redux frontend project contains production dependencies in package.json?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm

I've just started learning React.js+Redux and I see that a lot of frontend projects use `npm` as package manager.

Lets take this project for example - [counter](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/tree/master/examples/counter).

It contains [`package.json` file](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/examples/counter/package.json). If we take a look at contents of this file we will see that there are `devDependencies` and `dependencies` entries in it.

```
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^0.14.7",
    "react-dom": "^0.14.7",
    "react-redux": "^4.2.1",
    "redux": "^3.2.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.3.15",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.3.13",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.3.13",
    "babel-preset-react-hmre": "^1.1.1",
    "babel-register": "^6.3.13",
    "cross-env": "^1.0.7",
    "enzyme": "^2.0.0",
    "expect": "^1.6.0",
    "express": "^4.13.3",
    "mocha": "^2.2.5",
    "node-libs-browser": "^0.5.2",
    "react-addons-test-utils": "^0.14.7",
    "webpack": "^1.9.11",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^1.2.0",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.9.1"
  }
```

While I know what is the difference between `devDependencies` and `dependencies` I do not understand why the project lists `react`, `react-dom`, `redux` under `dependencies` section. From my understanding it is a frontend project which doesn't need anything installed on server to work in production.

Comment: All those projects (redux, react, react-dom) are frontend projects... not sure what you're asking?  Npm is a package manager, front/back end doesn't matter

Comment: @S.S.J Please use google search before posting a question on StackOverflow.

Comment: Package.json does not distinguish between frontend/backend.

Comment: @aarosil if it is a frontend project then why does it list dependencies under `dependencies`?

Comment: @bhargavponnapalli Could you please show me exact google search which answers my question? I did search google, but failed to find answer

Comment: @Himmel I do understand that. I do not understand _why the frontend project splits dependencies into two parts_ instead of keeping all of them in `devDependencies`

Comment: sounds like you dont understand the differences... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18875674/whats-the-difference-between-dependencies-devdependencies-and-peerdependencies

Comment: @JordanHendrix I read the answer you've linked. My question still stands. Why does the project splits dependencies into `devDependencies` and `dependencies`? What is the point of having `react` installed on a production server in this case?

Comment: @S.S.J http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30451556/what-is-the-correct-way-of-adding-a-dependency-to-react-in-your-package-json-for

Comment: "Counter" is a web application that uses React. Typically, libraries that are used in the app are added as `dependencies`.

Answer (score 0):

As @aarosil points out, `npm` doesn't care about front end or back end. It's just a package manager.

So it all comes down to the project structure. Looking at the example you gave (the React [counter](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/tree/master/examples/counter) example), this is a very small demo that runs in the browser. It uses webpack to build the project, which in this case consists of a JS bundle which is requested by the browser & runs in the browser. This bundle includes those dependencies you see in the `package.json` file, which also run in the browser.

You could just as easily use `npm` to build a "back end" package for use on the server side. In that case, the dependencies would probably not include `react`, etc. (unless, of course, you want to render pages on the server)