# Where should I include React as a dependency in my UI components library?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, dependencies, styled-components

I am building a UI components library for react based on `styled-components`. Should I install `react` as a devDependency or as a normal dependency?

(And possibly, other direct dependencies such as `prop-types`, `recompose`, `formik` etc)

And Why?

(Note: I assumed this to have been asked before in SO, but couldn't find a similar question. If this is a duplicate, I'll take this down immediately. Thanks)

Edit: Please don't provide opinionated answers. I am looking for answers like, "Your app will crash, if you install it as a  dependency..."

Comment: go ahead with React being a dependency, your components will need `React` to run themselves  even in production, and npm does not install dev dependencies in production

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30451556/what-is-the-correct-way-of-adding-a-dependency-to-react-in-your-package-json-for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `peerDependencies`.

**WHY?** *([From yarn docs](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/dependency-types/#toc-peerdependencies))*

> Peer dependencies are a special type of dependency that would only
>   ever come up if you were publishing your own package.
>
> Having a peer dependency means that your package needs a dependency
>   that is the same exact dependency as the person installing your
>   package. This is useful for packages like react that need to have a
>   single copy of react-dom that is also used by the person installing
>   it.

More info: [Peer Dependecies blog post on nodejs.org](https://nodejs.org/en/blog/npm/peer-dependencies/)

Comment: But why should he user peer dependencies if he is not publishing his own package?

Comment: He did not say anything about publishing. He might be going to or not, nevertheless he is creating a library depends on another library and there might be some version problem if the future possible user tries to use it. @MatthewBarbara